# WPF can only open one window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Assuming two projects, a WinForms project and a WPF project, in the WinForms project there is no problem with the following code being in Main() and removing the Application.Run:

```
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Form1 window = new Form1();
            window.Show();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            window.Close();
        }
```

However, in the WPF application, removing the StartupUri="Window1.xaml" and then creating:

```
    public App()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Window window = new Window();
            window.Show();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```

The program loops indefinitely but the Window only opens up once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the ShutdownMode like so

```
public App()
{
    this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Window window = new Window();
        window.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        window.Close();
    }
    //Will never get here with this sample code,
    //but this would be how you close the app.
    this.Shutdown();

}
```

Otherwise WPF treats closing the first window opened as shutting down the application. Although the code in the loop will continue to run.

> The lifetime of some applications may
>   not be dependent on when the main
>   window or last window is closed, or
>   may not be dependent on windows at
>   all. For these scenarios you need to
>   set the ShutdownMode property to
>   OnExplicitShutdown, which requires an
>   explicit Shutdown method call to stop
>   the application. Otherwise, the
>   application continues running in the
>   background.

[MSDN:ShutdownMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!
I had this problem with a modal login dialog being shown and then WPF quitting without any message or exceptions before the main window would display.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally if you remove the StartupUri you should load the MainWindow in the Application.Startup event

```
public App() 
{
  Startup += App_Startup
}

public void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    MainWindow = new Window();
    MainWindow.Show();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    MainWindow.Close();
  }
}
```

Although, I'm not sure if this will work either.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That doesn't work either. And the Startup event args take StartupEventArgs.

Comment: Nothing malicious, on a separate thread I am checking if a .XAML file has been updated. If it has I want to reload the main window using XamlReader.Load(fileStream);